# RedShift Group Vs Roles

Tags: amazon-redshift, rbac

I am getting confused between the group and role concept in RedShift. When do we use groups and when are roles used? I was trying to understand it from typical RBAC implementation in other products, but could not match it with how RedShift has implemented it. It looks like it is continuing with PostgreSQL legacy approach

Answer (score 4):

You can't have groups inheriting groups. Roles can inherit other roles. Unless you need tiered hierarchies, groups and users are easier to manage and you can get all the information you need to manage users and groups using the admin views in the amazon redshift utilities https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/AdminViews

In Redshift, nobody has permission to see the pg_roles tables and I still haven't found a way out to see which GRANTs are assigned to a given ROLE. Without this, administration of roles is a bit trickier in Redshift.

Comment: I had to dig around a bit, and found out that tables (or any object stored in `pg_class`) have their grants stored in `pg_class.relacl`, just like in Postgres (and with `psql` you can also see them when issuing `\dp`).  Role memberships are available in `svv_user_grants`.

Comment: Thanks @dezso for pointing me in the right direction. The system views `svv_system_privileges` and `svv_user_grants` are also useful. And then to get the grants assigned to a role (which I was struggling with in my initial reply), you can use the `svv_relation_privileges` with identity_type = 'role'.